# how to convert string to array of 32 bit integers?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I want to send the string to an encryption function which accepts an array of four (32-bit) integers.
So how to convert string to array of 32 bit integers in javascript and divide it to send it to function?

Comment: "send it to function" ... where is this function? Is it a JavaScript function?  Is it a web service?  Are you running JavaScript in a web browser context or some other server-side system?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This smells of homework, but here you go.

---

**Method 1:**

Assuming you want to convert four characters in a string to ints, this will work:

```
// Declare your values.
var myString = "1234";

// Convert your string array to an int array.
var numberArray[myString.length];
for (var i = 0; i < myString.length]; i++)
{
    numberArray[i] = int.parseInt(myString[i]);
}

// Call your function.
MyEncryptionFunction(numberArray);
```

---

**Method 2:**

Assuming you want to convert four characters to the numeric values of their chars, this will work:

```
// Declare your values.
var myString = "1,2,3,4";

// Convert your string array to an int array.
var numberArray[myString.length];
for (var i = 0; i < myString.length]; i++)
{
    numberArray[i] = myString.charCodeAt(i);
}

// Call your function.
MyEncryptionFunction(numberArray);
```

---

**Method 3:**

Assuming you want to split a group of four numbers separated by a consistent delimiter, this will work.

```
// Declare your values.
var splitter = ",";
var myString = "1,2,3,4";

// Convert myString to a string array.
var stringArray[] = myString.split(splitter);

// Convert your string array to an int array.
var numberArray[stringArray.length];
for (var i = 0; i < stringArray.length]; i++)
{
    numberArray[i] = int.parseInt(stringArray[i]);
}

// Call your function.
MyEncryptionFunction(numberArray);
```

Comment: if characters in string are not separated by comma then how can we convert string to stringArray?

Comment: @vaichidrewar: I made that the new **Method 1**.

Answer (score 1):

Use `string.charCodeAt(i)`, to get the numeric char code of string `string` at position *i*. Depending on your used encryption, you can apply an own compression method, to combine multiple char codes (most char codes are far smaller than 32 bits).

Example of separating a string in an array consisting of pairs (4 chars):

```
var string = "A sstring dum doo foo bar";
var result = [];
string += Array((5-(string.length%4))%5).join(" "); //Adding padding at the end
for(var i=3, len=string.length; i<len; i+=4){
    result.push([string.charCodeAt(i-3), string.charCodeAt(i-2),
             string.charCodeAt(i-1), string.charCodeAt(i)]);
}
```